# Code Hard-Wrapping and Advanced Indentation/Alignment in Vim Script

Tags: vim, alignment, indentation

**Code Hard-Wrapping.** I've configured Vim to automatically (as I type) hard wrap long lines of comments on 80 columns. Works well. However, it does not seem to wrap code automatically. I thought adding `set formatoptions+=t` (currently I have `set formatoptions=c,r,q,a,n`) would do the trick, but it does not. Additionally, in Vim Script it would be great if Vim could put backward slash `\` automatically when line continuation is required due to hard-wrapping. So is there a way to achieve hard-wrapping for code and such advanced features?

**Advanced Indentation/Alignment.** I like to use `gg=G` - I even attached it as a pre-hook to writing file. I have `cindent` enabled. Now I wonder is it possible to write `indentexpr` or maybe tweak some other variable to achieve the following for Vim Script code, for example:

```
" Before gg=G
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['^', '\s', ',', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{',
  \'}', '<', '>', '''', '"']

" After gg=G
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['^', '\s', ',', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{',
                                \'}', '<', '>', '''', '"']
```

I tried to add `vim.vim` file into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` with the following contents:

```
setlocal indentexpr=IndentExpression()

fun IndentExpression()
  let indent = cindent(v:lnum)
  let match = matchstr(getline(v:lnum - 1), '^\s*\S\+\s\+\S\+\s*=\s*\[\ze.*$')

  if !empty(match)
    let indent = len(match)
  endif

  return indent
endf
```

But I was out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `'formatoptions'`: When you have `a` in there, there's no need for `t`; the former automatically wraps as you type, so the line break when the text width is reached (which the latter does), will happen, anyway. What's causing problem is the `c`, because that restricts the auto-format to comments. Cp. `:help fo-table`:

> a Automatic formatting of paragraphs.  Every time text is inserted or
>   deleted the paragraph will be reformatted.  See |auto-format|.
>   When the 'c' flag is present this only happens for recognized
>   comments.

So, a `:set fo-=c` should do the trick.